# How to Resolve Angularjs file or Directory Not Found Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022

My Application is running with Asp.net Mvc5 and Angularjs 1.6.9 and Bower is used as package manager.
Recently My laptop is crashed so i have to install Operating System again since then my application is not running successfully in my local system.
Application is running fine in production and other dev environments.
I have installed node and bower components after laptop crash.
But Still my application is throwing File or Directory Not Found Issue.
Please find the attached images (Angularjs File ERROR Image[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IGKd.png) && Angularjs File Not Found Image[attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2sgS.png)) for reference.
My application is running with below technologies.
Asp.net MVC
Angular js 1.6.9
.net Framework 4.6
Visual Studio 2022
Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is injector error for scheduleService ,please check if it is present in the right folder of project or included in your index.html.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply yes issue is with schedulerservice it is a typescript file but unable to convert it to javascript file thats why it is not working in local and working fine in production and other environments. Typescript npm module is already installed. Do i need to add any Path Variable??

Comment: Yes please try to install it separately